Current drawn with uln2003 together with mcp23017 or PCF8575
I’m using ULN2003A for driving 28BYJ-48 on my ESP32. SInce I need many motors I need to multiplex. I’m going to use either MCP23017 or PCF8575. Ive read however that MCP23017 has a maximum current per pin rating of around 25 mA.
The 28BYJ-48, it's typically around 150-200 mA per phase according to specs. The ULN2003A can handle this since ULN2003A can handle up to 500 mA per output.
The main concern is the current drawn by the ULN2003A's input pins, which are connected to the MCP23017 output pins. Will MCP23017 be alright with driving this? Will it current-wise be ok to drive four ULN2003A with 28BYJ-48
Here is the specs for ULN2003A:

UPDATE
I made this quick sketch in Fritzing. (sorry for not providing a proper schematic)


Have you compared how much IO expanders can output current vs how much ULN2003A input needs? What is the concern?

The concern is the input current on uln2003a. Im going to use 4 uln2003a on mcp23017 so all 16 possible pins will be used.

The current reads in the data sheet, so what is the concern about it? Also that changes things if you are driving current out from 16 pins simultaneously, or just drive one motor at a time. But even if you did, you can't drive all 16 pins high simultaneously because you can't drive current through all 4 coils of a single motor simultaneously. Only 2 coils per motor can be activated max at one given time.

To help get an answer can you edit the question and show a schematic of the interconnections. Each ULN2003A has 7 drivers per package, and so with 4 ULN2003A devices used that means a total of 28 drivers, which is more than the 16 I/O ports on a MCP23017.

Your question is answered in the ULN's datasheet. Please link to the version that you're using, and tell what exact part in it you do not understand.

According to the specs for uln2003a it comsumes about 1.35 mA maximum. So I guess there wouldnt be any problem then. Im using this driverboard:
https://www.electrokit.com/en/drivkort-for-stegmotorer-uln2003a
So my idea is to just connect 16 outputspins to four uln2003a driver boards.

The ULN2003 is rated up to 2mA input current at 5V, or like you found, 1.35mA at 3.85V.
The MCP23017 is rated to output at least  3.8V or more at 3mA, when supply voltage is 4.5V.
So they would seem compatible, assuming you use the MCP at higher voltage than 4.5V.
When you said you have heard that the IO expander has a maximum current rating of 25mA per pin, it is correct but it may not mean what you think it means.
The 25mA is an absolute maximum value that is the limit of damage, and you can reach or exceed this by e.g. short circuiting an IO pin to supply or ground when the pin is an output.
Also the VDD supply pin has absolute maximum value of 125mA, so you can't even source 8mA per pin from all 16 pins as you will hit the damage limit.
It is best to stay far away from the damage limits, preferably even within the nominal rated limits.
The area between guaranteed operating limits and absolute maximum limits is a bit of a gray area - it means the chip does not degrade or permanently damage, but it also means the chip does not have to operate normally if you use it out of guaranteed operating limits.
The PCF8575 is not rated to output enough current for ULN input.

Thanks. I made a quick sketch with all connections in fritzing. I think it should be ok?
